# How to add values to a specific matrix row-column

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following matrix:

```
1  2  3  4 
2  3  4  5
```

and I want to add 10 to 3rd column 2nd row:

```
1  2  3  4
2  3  14  5
```

How should I do it?

Comment: please, read the manuals for R carefully first. This and a lot of other very basic knowledge is explained in there. You have a wide choice of manuals on this website : http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html next to the nice link csgillespie gave you.

Answer (score 9):

If `m` is your matrix, then

```
> m = matrix(0, 2, 4)
> m[2,3] = m[2,3] + 10
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0   10    0
```

Any book in R will have details on how to access specific elements. In the meantime have a look at Chapter 5 of [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf)

Comment: please use `<-` for assignment, not `=` !!

Comment: @Prasad, no I prefer "=" for a variety reasons. For example, I use "=" in every other language I program in, I teach undergraduates who then get taught fortran (which uses "=") so continuity, I don't have use strange underscore bindings in emacs....

Comment: woo-hoo, assignment operator war!

Comment: Personally, for me, `<-` supports better readability, especially when reviewing others' code.  I tend to find that `<-` is much easier on the eyes when the code is long and full of functions (since functions' arguments mostly use `=`, with rare exceptions).  Hence, `<-` makes it easier to spot the objects quickly since the objects are assigned with `<-` and frequently are followed up with functions with multiple arguments.  Google's R Style Guide also recommends `<-` over `=`: https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#assignment.